# Search images in a directory using glob with case-insensitivity

Tags: php, regex, glob, case-insensitive

I'm trying to get images in a directory (with extensions jpg, jpeg, png, gif) using [glob()](http://php.net/glob). Here's my code:

```
$images = glob("uploads/*.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif}", GLOB_BRACE);
```

Because `glob()` is case sensitive, it's unable to find files with upper case and mixed case extensions. I want to find files with UPPERCASE (JPG, JPEG, PNG, GIF) and mixed case (JpG, jPeG, PNg, gIF) extensions.

I managed it to work using [sql_regcase()](http://php.net/sql_regcase) on one extension, but it is now deprecated anyway.

```
$pattern = sql_regcase("jpg");
$images = glob("uploads/*.$pattern", GLOB_BRACE);
```

Is there any flexible solution for this problem?

Comment: @Michael Thanks for your quick response. But, none of those solutions work with multiple extensions.

Comment: Yours will be messier, but the same principle applies:  `glob("uploads/*.{[jJ][pP][gG],[gG][iI][fF]}", GLOB_BRACE)`  it'll work...

Comment: This is working
`glob("uploads/*.[jJ][pP][gG]", GLOB_BRACE)`. This is working too
`glob("uploads/*.[gG][iI][fF]", GLOB_BRACE)`. This doesn't. `glob("uploads/*.{[jJ][pP][gG],[gG][iI][fF]}", GLOB_BRACE)`. It returns an empty array(). I couldn't make it work with multiple extensions. Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: Then use the `preg_grep('/\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/i')` approach for filtering the `glob` list.

Comment: What PHP version do you have? The exact same glob worked correctly for me testing on 5.5. That's why I suggested it.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski I'm running PHP 5.4, may be the syntax you've posted doesn't support in older versions. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @mario I used preg_grep() to make my code work. Thank you very much, bro.

Comment: @Kiran From 5.4 to 5.5 there are no documented changes.More likely, it could be a platform or underlying OS library difference. Mine worked on Linux, for example. In any case if `preg_grep()` works for you, that's sufficient.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42461547/php-glob-with-case-insensitive-matching/42464571#42464571