# PHP glob with case-insensitive matching

Tags: php, glob

I use `glob` for finding folders as

```
$str = "Test Folder";
$folder = glob("$dir/*$str*");
```

How can I tell `glob` to match to find the matching folders case-insensitive?

Matching *test folder*, *TEST FOLDER*, etc.

NOTE that `$str` is an unknown input to the script!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can PHP's glob() be made to find files in a case insensitive manner?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2520612/can-phps-glob-be-made-to-find-files-in-a-case-insensitive-manner)

Comment: try `[a-zA-Z]` as range...

Comment: Why did you delete your comment?

Comment: @VishalKumarSahu that's for a constant part of the pattern. `$str` is unknown here. How do you define it with the regex pattern?

Comment: You will get an array from GLOB... and in that array you can play what you want.

Comment: @VishalKumarSahu range of what? can you suggest a pattern?

Comment: @VishalKumarSahu when glob does not match, the folder will not be in the array to be played with.

Comment: [See](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php#88250) this thread on php.net this could be of some use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

May I suggest the build of case-insensitive character ranges on each letter of `$str`?

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/08c39b52aebbb5e364a48de7a7b01c4f342c5511))

```
function glob_i($string){  // this function is not multi-byte ready.
    $result='';  // init the output string to allow concatenation
    for($i=0,$len=strlen($string); $i<$len; ++$i){  // loop each character
        if(ctype_alpha($string[$i])){  // check if it is a letter
            $result.='['.lcfirst($string[$i]).ucfirst($string[$i]).']';  // add 2-character pattern
        }else{
            $result.=$string[$i];  // add non-letter character
        }
    }
    return $result;  // return the prepared string
}
$dir='public_html';
$str='Test Folder';

echo glob_i($str);  // [tT][eE][sS][tT] [fF][oO][lL][dD][eE][rR]
echo "\n";
echo "$dir/*",glob_i($str),'*';  // public_html/*[tT][eE][sS][tT] [fF][oO][lL][dD][eE][rR]*
```

If you require a multibyte version, this is my suggested snippet: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c19aae5cef5267ded647abe82c1fa696868f98a4))

```
function glob_im($string,$encoding='utf8'){
    $result='';
    for($i=0,$len=mb_strlen($string); $i<$len; ++$i){
        $l=mb_strtolower(mb_substr($string,$i,1,$encoding));
        $u=mb_strtoupper(mb_substr($string,$i,1,$encoding));
        if($l!=$u){
            $result.="[{$l}{$u}]";
        }else{
            $result.=mb_substr($string,$i,1,$encoding);
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
$dir='public_html';
$str='testovací složku';

echo glob_im($str);  // [tT][eE][sS][tT][oO][vV][aA][cC][íÍ] [sS][lL][oO][žŽ][kK][uU]
echo "\n";
echo "$dir/*",glob_im($str),'*';  // public_html/*[tT][eE][sS][tT][oO][vV][aA][cC][íÍ] [sS][lL][oO][žŽ][kK][uU]*
```

Related Stackoverflow page:

[Can PHP's glob() be made to find files in a case insensitive manner?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2520612/can-phps-glob-be-made-to-find-files-in-a-case-insensitive-manner)

---

p.s. If you don't mind the expense of regex and/or you prefer a condensed one-liner, this will do the same: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4b31be15923a67c4fef10eb49bc6fdba2fee8fbf))

```
$dir='public_html';
$str='Test Folder';
echo "$dir/*",preg_replace_callback('/[a-z]/i',function($m){return '['.lcfirst($m[0]).ucfirst($m[0])."]";},$str),'*';  // $public_html/*[tT][eE][sS][tT] [fF][oO][lL][dD][eE][rR]*
```

and here is the multi-byte version: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2f6f5d7e0f975ec9ddeafb20d4f183139eec738d))

```
$encoding='utf8';
$dir='public_html';
$str='testovací složku';
echo "$dir/*",preg_replace_callback('/\pL/iu',function($m)use($encoding){return '['.mb_strtolower($m[0],$encoding).mb_strtoupper($m[0],$encoding)."]";},$str),'*';  // public_html/*[tT][eE][sS][tT][oO][vV][aA][cC][íÍ] [sS][lL][oO][žŽ][kK][uU]*
```