# How to find pathnames matching a pattern using PHP

Tags: php

I'm looking for files in a directory. My directory pathname pattern looks like this:

- TEST_1.jpg
- TEST_2.jpg
- TEST_3.jpg
- TEST_4.jpg
- twPL_1.jpg
- twPL_2.jpg
- twPL_3.jpg
- twPL_4.jpg

so if i have an URL Parameter with localhost:8000/covers?**customer=twPL**. I'm getting the first two jpg's and this is working. The problem is that the URL Parameter is case sensitive. If i try to write the URL Paramater with lower case characters (...?**customer=twpl**) i'm getting a notice :

> Notice: Undefined offset: 0
>
> Notice: Undefined offset: 1

```
<?php
        if(isset($_GET["customer"])) {
            $customer = $_GET["customer"];
            $dirs = glob("cover/".$customer."*.jpg");
            $allData = glob("cover/*.jpg");
            $killExt = array("cover/","_1","_2","_3","_4",".jpg");
            $new_array = str_replace($killExt, "", $allData);
            $arrayLowerCase = array_map('strtolower', $new_array);

            // die(var_dump($dirs));

            if(array_search(strtolower($customer), $arrayLowerCase) !== false){
                for($i=0; $i < 2; $i++) {
                    echo 
                    '<div class="cover" data-page-number="0">',
                        '<img class="front-modal" src="'.strtolower($dirs[$i]).'"/>',
                    '</div>';
                }
            }   
        }
    ?>
```

I think this causes the problem `$dirs = glob("cover/".$customer."*.jpg");`
how can i search in this glob function in a case insensitive way...

Comment: You can use `strtolower` before checking.

Comment: you mean to set the $customer to `strtolower` ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to start with a rule than you define : name in lower or in caps. So, it's easier to just lowercase all $_GET parameters than doing what you want to do. 
Whatever.

For your problem, you can, by regexp, search all the patern matching your two files name :
TEST : Test, TEsT, etc 
twPL : twpl, TWPL etc

```
//this will find all pattern of twpl
preg_match("/twpl/i", $_GET["customer"], $matches_twpl);
preg_match("/test/i", $_GET["customer"], $matches_test);
```

and then

```
$safe_cust = "";
if(strtolower($matches_twpl[0]) == "twpl"){
    $safe_cust = "twPL";
} else if ( strtolower($matches_test[0]) == "test") {
    $safe_cust = "TEST"; 
}else {
    //error
}
```

Comment: how your cover name are defined?

Comment: different... there is no pattern for the names

Comment: this helped me. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42461547/php-glob-with-case-insensitive-matching